# nowjs/node-proxy fails to install on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, npm, nowjs-sockets

I'm trying to install now.js on ubuntu 11.10 (running on windows with wubi, if that matters). I've downloaded and installed node, npm, and socket.io just fine, but `sudo npm install now` fails for some reason. I've tried with and without sudo, tried installing it globally, same error. Make is installed just fine...is it some problem with the node-proxy package? For what it's worth, trying `npm install node-proxy` produces a similar error.

node version 0.6.2
npm version 1.0.106
ubuntu 11.10 (windows with wubi)

The log reads, when I try to install now:

```
npm WARN node-proxy@0.5.2 package.json: bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']

> node-proxy@0.5.2 install /home/my_name/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy
> make

BUILDING: C++ Component
/bin/sh: node-waf: not found
cp: cannot stat `src/build/*/node-proxy.node': No such file or directory
make: *** [all] Error 1
npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2 Error: node-proxy@0.5.2 install: `make`
npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2 `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 2
npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at maybeExit (child_process.js:359:16)
npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at Process.onexit (child_process.js:395:5)
npm ERR! error installing now@0.7.6 Error: node-proxy@0.5.2 install: `make`
npm ERR! error installing now@0.7.6 `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 2
npm ERR! error installing now@0.7.6     at ChildProcess. (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR! error installing now@0.7.6     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
npm ERR! error installing now@0.7.6     at maybeExit (child_process.js:359:16)
npm ERR! error installing now@0.7.6     at Process.onexit (child_process.js:395:5)
npm ERR! node-proxy@0.5.2 install: `make`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node-proxy@0.5.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-proxy package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     make
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-proxy
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.0.0-13-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "now"
npm ERR! cwd /home/my_name
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/my_name/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be that `node-waf` is missing.

node-waf is a tool that is included with node which allows compiling binary modules, such as node-proxy.

You can test to see if node-waf is available simply by typing `node-waf` into the terminal to see if the command can be found. If not, you will need to reinstall node (run `make install` again) to make sure node-waf is available.