# Missing node-waf when installing nowjs

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

This seems like it can be a recent problem since there are new versions out for both node.js and nowjs. When trying to install nowjs on ubuntu 11.04 with node 0.7.0-pre and npm

```
sudo npm install now -g
```

I get

```
/bin/sh: node-waf: not found
```

and so make of node-proxy fails. Reinstalling node gets me nowhere. A little help please? I have tried #nowjs at freenode, but it is silent...

And yes, I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8283708/nowjs-node-proxy-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-11-10), but the answer doesn't make sense to me. node-waf is indeed missing, but how would running the same make install on node again remedy that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess would be that node-waf was somehow uninstalled, or removed from the path, or was never installed at all. If I were in your position, I'd give that solution a try.

Comment: I agree and will try that. Download the tarball from here http://code.google.com/p/waf/ and compile I guess. Crossing fingers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to install nodejs-dev. node-waf belongs to that package

Answer (score 5):

I tried to install on a new Ubuntu VM and eventually discovered I needed a C++ compiler. This did the trick for me:

```
$ sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev curl git core
$ npm install now
```

via [How to compile/install node.js(could not configure a cxx compiler!) (Ubuntu).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329355/node-js-could-not-configure-a-cxx-compiler-ubuntu)

Comment: Had the same setting (Ubuntu VM), so the combination of both answers worked for me.

Comment: @roufamatic shouldn't it be `git-core` at the end of the first command? You're missing the `-` :D

Answer (score 0):

Installing node-waf wasn't helping at all.

I simply upgraded my node version (from 0.4.4 into 0.6.2), problem was resolved!

Answer (score -1):

node-waf got changed to node-gyp, node-waf wont be supported in windows.

Answer (score -3):

Well. and now  **npm install nodejs-dev** fail